# How to manipulate Screen Color temperature in android like f.lux

Tags: java, android, screen

I am trying to develop an app that let user control warmness of screen on per app basis. This feature comes in miui by name of reading mode.

Behaviour I am trying to achieve is represented here: http://en.miui.com/thread-170033-1-1.html

I don't know what to use in Android to achieve the same. Are there any APIs or Classes in android available that can help me?

Comment: Did you manage to get some sample code working?

Answer (score 4):

You need to communicate with SurfaceFlinger and send it a color transformation matrix (transaction 1015, token "android.ui.ISurfaceComposer", data consists of a 32-bit integer followed by 16 floats). Have a look in Android source code for [SurfaceFlinger.cpp](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/SurfaceFlinger.cpp) as well as the color inversion code in the [system accessibility settings](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/accessibility/java/com/android/server/accessibility/DisplayAdjustmentUtils.java). This lets you set any color transform matrix you like. At least that's how I do it in my [ColorChanger app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.red).

You can then use the custom color transform matrix to remap the color temperature.

Unless you have a system signature for your app, you will need to use root, and then either communicate natively with SurfaceFlinger or launch some java code that uses a fair amount of reflection.

Moreover, this only works for Android 5.0 or higher. My ColorChanger has a very hackish way of making it work on 4.4, but trust me, you don't want to go there (I did, because I only had a 4.4 device when I wrote it).

Alternately, you can do some even lower level stuff like [CF.lumen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.lumen&hl=en) does. I think Chainfire rewrites parts of the display driver. I am not sure this works if you don't have write access to /system.

Comment: Link to your app 'ColorChanger App' is broken. Anyway, thanks for replying. Is this the only way to achieve the described behaviour.

Comment: To my knowledge these are the only ways to do it on a wide variety of devices. Samsung Galaxy S devices have an MDNIE system that allows for a lot of color control. I used it in my Galactic Night app, but that app hasn't been working in newer models. Perhaps could be updated, but there is too much difference between models for it to be worth doing, unless you happen to own one of the models and need it yourself.